# ant jar error: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program...${aapt}": error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, android, macos, unity-game-engine, jar

I'm trying to compile a simple Java library for Unity, and after running ant jar, I get the following message:

```
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Applications/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:694: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/****/UnityProjects/****/JavaTestPlugin/${aapt}": error=2, No such file or directory
```

This is strange, because I've compiled this class before successfully, and I have everything I would think I need. Namely Android Studio, and related packages (Tools, Android 4/5, etc). I noticed that aapt is not located in my adt-bundle/sdk/platform-tools directory, but it is in one of the build-tools directories. Even including the latter in my path did not help.

Anyway, I am running Mac OS 10.10.3, with the most up-to-date version of Android Studio. This class compiled before upgrading to Yosemite. I've seen suggestions on how to fix this issue, but all of those suggestions apply to Linux as opposed to Mac OS.

Comment: The proper tag for Unity3D is unity3d.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Have you updated the Android SDK tools to 24.3.2? This seems to have caused the issue. Add following 4 lines to android-sdk-path/tools/ant/build.xml starting line 484 and hopefully it should solve.

```
<property name="aidl" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/aidl${exe}" />
<property name="aapt" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/aapt${exe}" />
<property name="dx" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/dx${bat}" />
<property name="zipalign" location="${android.build.tools.dir}/zipalign${exe}" />
```

Comment: This fixes the same error also on Linux-64 version of Android SDK.

Comment: Thanks man. I was struggling from last 3 days. And finally boom!

Comment: Yes, I am using that version of the Android SDK tools. Thank for the fix; it helped.

Comment: Big up for you! It worked on my macbook as well. I was just getting started with NativeScript, running the hello world app. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in the latest tools update ( https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176488 )

Comment: Thanks for the update. 

Sad but It's really the time to move from Ant. If Google doesn't test this part of the code before releasing, that's an indication that it's no longer aligned to Google's roadmap. We migrated most of the projects except those in maintenance phase to gradle. Some of us uses gradle command line and rest of us  Android studio - one good thing about gradle is that you no longer need to separately maintain configuration file which was the case with Ant.